# Mapping a table called "group" in Hibernate for DB2 and HSQLDB

Tags: hibernate, db2, hsqldb, hibernate-mapping

I have a table called *group*, that I am trying to map using hibernate for DB2 and [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/). Table name *group* is a reserved word and it must be quoted in HSQLDB. However DB2 does not like quoted table name.

So this mapping works in HSQLDB but not in DB2:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="`group`")
public class Group {
```

Mapping results in following error in DB2 (making a query that involves Group table):

```
Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.SqlException: DB2 SQL error: SQLCODE: -204, SQLSTATE: 42704, SQLERRMC: SCHEMA_NAME.group
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.hh.c(hh.java:1662)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.hh.d(hh.java:1650)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.hh.a(hh.java:1219)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.db.g(db.java:139)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.db.a(db.java:39)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.t.a(t.java:34)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.sb.f(sb.java:142)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.hh.n(hh.java:1190)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.ih.eb(ih.java:1997)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.ih.d(ih.java:2439)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.ih.V(ih.java:492)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.ih.executeQuery(ih.java:475)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1787)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:674)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadCollection(Loader.java:1994)
    ... 71 more
```

And this works in DB2 but not in HSQLDB:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="group")
public class Group {
```

Mapping results in following error in HSQLDB (creating the Group table):

```
WARN hibernate.ExtendedAnnotatedSessionFactoryBean - Unsuccessful schema statement: create table group  ( *details omitted* )
java.sql.SQLException: Unexpected token: GROUP in statement [create table group]
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.executeSchemaStatement(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:1000)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.executeSchemaScript(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:972)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean$2.doInHibernate(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:912)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.execute(HibernateTemplate.java:373)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.execute(HibernateTemplate.java:338)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.createDatabaseSchema(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:906)
  ...
```

I am using [org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/dialect/DB2Dialect.html) and [org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/dialect/HSQLDialect.html) for DB2 and HSQLDB, respectively.

How can I make the same mapping work for the both databases simultaneously?

Comment: It is not a good idea you use SQL keyword. If possible choose another table name.

Comment: First stack trace you posted suggests that your table name is not escaped **everywhere** - particularly there is some collection you've mapped that still refers to non-escaped table name. Second stack trace is expected - non-escaped name 'group' is invalid. It's a bit puzzling that it works in DB2 - I'm guessing its settings were changed and it uses different escape character now. You need to find out what it is and override the dialect to specify it in openQuote/closeQuote methods as I pointed in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up doing `create alias groups for group;` in DB2 and changing table name in HSQLDB, which solved my problem. Now I map *groups* table, and there are no longer this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using backticks (like in your first sample) should work but you have to use them **everywhere** the table name is mentioned.

[Dialect](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/dialect/Dialect.html) has [openQuote()](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/dialect/Dialect.html#openQuote()) and [closeQuote()](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/dialect/Dialect.html#closeQuote()) methods that translate those backticks into quotes appropriate for given database. Those default to double quote (") for most databases including DB2 and HSQL. I don't have either on hand right now to try this but I've had it working for DB2 / Oracle / MySQL combination in the past.

Can you post a specific error and the stack trace you're getting?

All that said, if you **can** change the table name to a non-reserved word I would strongly recommend that you do - you'll save yourself a lot of headache in the end.

Comment: I posted some stack traces. Sadly, I can't rename the table.

Comment: It seems that DB2 does not like quoting with "-characters:

db2 => select * from "group"
SQL0204N  "SCHEMA_NAME.group" is an undefined name.  SQLSTATE=42704