# Play 2.0 Framework - Reserved Table Name

Tags: java, mysql, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have created a model called Group which in turn should create the table group. As a result the database evolutes with errors, saying the table name is a reserved word. Due to the fact that my model/table name is a reserved word I would like to know if there is a way to keep my table named group.

Here is an example of my Group model (Play Framework 2.0):

```
@Entity
public class Group extends Model {

@Id         private long     id;    
@Required   private String   groupName;

private static Model.Finder<Long,Group> find = 
new Model.Finder<Long,Group>   (Long.class, Group.class);

public Group() {        
}

public Group(String groupName) {
    this.groupName = groupName;
}

    /*** Getters & Setters ***/
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getGroupName() {
        return groupName;
    }
    public void setGroupName(String groupName) {
        this.groupName = groupName;
    }

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: BTW: you don't need to create custom getters/setters in this case, `Ebean` will do it for you!

Answer (score 2):

Simple use

```
@Entity
@Table(name="groupOfxxx")
public class Group {
```

Something which describes the table without a reserved word.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564479/mapping-a-table-called-group-in-hibernate-for-db2-and-hsqldb) will help:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="`group`")
public class Group {
```

If not, try:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="group")
public class Group {
```

If not, try:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1565765/952046

**EDIT**

[MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) says:

> Most of the words in the table are forbidden by standard SQL as column
>   or table names (for example, GROUP).

[Furthermore](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifiers.html):

```
The identifier quote character is the backtick (“`”):

mysql> SELECT * FROM `select` WHERE `select`.id > 100;
```

So it should work. Maybe there's sth wrong with quotes - make sure you use tick mark (``` \``), not a single quote ( ```'`). You can also try setting`mysql> SET sql_mode='ANSI_QUOTES';`. Check if you can create table named`group` from MySQL console.

Comment: One would think that this works, but when it creates the keys, it tries to name them pk_`group`. Really silly!

Comment: Linked question suggests that this mapping depends on which db you want to use - for hsqldb (and probably few others) you don't need `\``.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention I am using MySQL. I have tried both of the above mentioned ways, but none of these work.

Comment: Thanks I will try that and get back to you regarding that asap